# bootstrap ie8 modal popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have googled this, and have tried the few answers I have found, but can't resolve my issue.

I have a modal popup that should appear on a button press. this works on all other browsers / versions but IE. One customer has to use IE 8 (all still on XP, but please no arguments about they should update. That's not going to happen in the near future.)

Here is a bit of my html code. (Form details omitted for brevity)

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="collect-email" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h3>Collect Customer Email</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
```

....

I have html5shiv loaded. I also have the js code below, which should remove the fade operation, and so make the modal work.

```
var ie = (function(){
    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );
    return v > 4 ? v : undef;
}());

$(document).ready(function () {        
    if (ie < 10) {
            jQuery('.fade').removeClass('fade');
    }
...
```

However, as soon as the page is browsed, the modal is visible. And pressing the close or ok buttons on the modal popup do not hide it again.

Update: I swapped my ie version detection code for this, which detects a specific feature.

```
  if( ! document.addEventListener  ){
        alert("you got IE8 or less");

        jQuery('.fade').removeClass('fade');
        $('#collect-email').modal({ show: false });
    }
```

The alert pops up, so it is catching the earlier browsers. fade is removed, so the issue is the line; 
 $('#collect-email').modal({ show: false }); which I added to try and force the modal to disappear.

Edit: Found Workaround.
If I manually hide and show the div wrapping the modal at the appropriate times, then the rest of the code works. So its not elegant, but as this is xp / ie8, I am not goign to lose too much sleep over it for now.

Comment: Instead of removing the class, you might try using the show method. Just in case it's doing something wonky under the hood. IE: jQuery('.modal').modal('show')

Comment: Thats what I am doing to show / hide the modal. My main concern right now is why it is visible from the offset, and never disappearing. I would hope that if I can crack that, then the rest should be easy

Comment: Sounds like there's some form of javascript error somewhere in there. IE has a bad habit of just stopping JS execution silently when it comes upon something it doesn't like. Do you have your code running through a linter?

Comment: something that checks code quality. http://www.jslint.com/ or some such.

Comment: jslint is picing up the wile , error as incorrect js, when it isn't, so I am not sure how much use it is in this case.). Guess I need to strip out al the js / jquery / bootstrap stuff, and add it in line by line to find the issue, and do this 'old school'

Comment: a linter is going to be VERY anal about what is or isn't technically correct. In this case, even though it works, separating statements with a comma in the while declaration is not correct javascript, so it's going to yell.

Answer (score 0):

Did it remove the fade class in your markup? (check via inspect element). If it is not, maybe your function is not correct. Have a look at  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/ as well

Comment: Yes it does remove the fade class, and we are usingjQuery 1.9, so I can't use jquery.browser

Comment: I see it is deprecated.. sorry for that